# Finding the length of a word in a string and finding how many words have that length. (Java)

Tags: java, string, count, cpu-word, string-length

I need some help finding the length of a word and how many word have that length. For example, if the sentence is `"I am going to find some string lengths"`,

The output would be

```
Number of String with length 1 is 1

Number of String with length 2 is 2

Number of String with length 4 is 2

Number of String with length 5 is 1

Number of String with length 6 is 1

Number of String with length 7 is 1
```

So far, I've got this:

```
    String word;
    int wordlength;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner inFile = 
            new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\WordSize.txt\\"));

    PrintWriter outFile = 
            new PrintWriter("wordsizes.out");

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        word = inFile.next();

        wordlength = word.length();

        if (count >= 0)
            outFile.println(wordlength);

        count++;
    }

    outFile.close();
        }
}
```

Which just gives the length of each word.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't really make sense, at least to me. Anyways, what is the issue you are facing? You haven't really asked a question.

Comment: Neither the question nor the code make senses to me! :(

Comment: Sorry guys! I was trying to find a way to explain it clearly, but let me try again.

I need to find the length of each word in the string. After the length of each word is found, I need to make a list of how many words are of each length. So if there's three words with 5 letters and two words with 6 letters, I need it to say that.

Comment: @Matt, un-deleted the answer. sorry i was unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense about your out put to me. I thing following will work for you.

```
String str="I am going to find some string lengths";
  String[] arr=str.split(" ");
    Map<Integer,Integer> lengthMap=new HashMap<>();
    for(String i:arr){
        Integer val=lengthMap.get(i.length());
        if(val==null){
           val=0;
        }
        lengthMap.put(i.length(),val+1);
    }
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> i:lengthMap.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Number of String with length "+i.getKey()+" is "+i.getValue());
    }
```

Out put

```
  Number of String with length 1 is 1
  Number of String with length 2 is 2
  Number of String with length 4 is 2
  Number of String with length 5 is 1
  Number of String with length 6 is 1
  Number of String with length 7 is 1
```

Comment: Yes! This is the output I want. Unfortunately, I'm in a beginner Java course that hasn't covered many of the methods you've used to solve my problem. But you've answered it correctly. Also, I've edited my original post to include the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

it is actually easy with `string.split()` function.  I am writing to demonstrate a solution:

```
String inputStr = "I am going to find some string lengths";
String str[] = inputStr.split(" "); // split the strings: "I", "am", "going", etc

int maxSize = 0;

for(String s: str)   // finding the word with maximum size and take its length
  if(maxSize < s.length())
        maxSize = s.length();

int lCount[] = new int[maxSize+1]; 


for(String s1: str)
{
   lCount[s1.length()]++; // count each length's occurance
}

 for(int j=0; j<lCount.length;j++)
 {
     System.out.println("String length: "+j+" count: "+lCount[j]);
 }
```

Comment: What happens when the String is *String inputStr = "I am going to find some string lengths withoutanyerrors";*. Never use the length of a String as an index. Its a very, very dangerous scenario.

Comment: i put a comment right below lCount initialization to let him know that size of lCount should be computed first, because i knew it was wrong

Comment: Why would you post a wrong solution then?! You could have just done `size of MaxWord * str.length` yourself and posted the right solution. Wouldn't that have been better?!

Comment: yes, but should not the OP figure it out himself? I was just planning to demonstrate instead of writing a full working solution so just he could copy and paste